# html5 validation on invalid event listener not firing

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a form in my html with following markup

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fname" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I also have 2 script tags one for jquery and the other for my javascript which I call validate.js

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script></body>
```

When I put the following code into my validate.js file and submit invalid data.  The page alerts 'invalid' as expected.

```
$("form input").on("invalid", function() {
     alert("invalid");
});
```

When I use this code in validate.js instead, when I click on the input the page again behaves as expected this time alerting 'click'.

```
$("body").on("click", "form input", function(){alert("click");});
```

However the following code does not work.  When invalid data is submitted the invalid event handler does not fire and 'invalid' is not alerted as it should be.

```
$("body").on("invalid", "form input", function(){alert("invalid");});
```

I would like to do it this way because in my application I add a form to my page from an ajax request and therefore I want to attach the event handler to the body rather than the form itself.  Is there any reason why this is not working?

Comment: Have a look to the [setCustomValidity(error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128882/set-input-as-invalid) function.

Comment: Could you add the form to the page to begin with, and then add the *fields* dynamically? That way you could register the event handler on the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("body").on("invalid", "form input", function(){alert("invalid");});`
This might not work because this is a live event, where the event is attached to body and triggers invalid for body and not for form input.

`$("body").on("click", "form input", function(){alert("invalid");});`
For example if we change it to click, the event listens to body click and then propagates the event to form input.

Try using the direct selector.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what you mean by the direct selector?

Comment: Like in your first alert('invalid') example.
Does your forms load up through ajax or on fly?

Comment: They go on the form using something along the lines of  $targetDiv.replaceWith($newHtml);  where the $newHtml contains my form and perhaps other stuff.

Comment: So just insert you invalid event call after the replace statement, Thats my opinion unless you find any other option to do so.

Comment: Ok I've go you.  I just need to add something like  $targetDiv.find("form input").on("invalid", function() {
     alert("invalid");
});   Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes correct and it should go after the '$targetDiv.replaceWith($newHtml);' statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody wondering about the actual reason this is not working, it's in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589524/11141417) answer:

> The invalid event does not bubble, it says so in the documentation, so delegated event handlers won't work as the event won't bubble up.